# Importing python modules in vscode

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

Recently downloaded vscode on macOS, but I seem unable to import any python modules. I've made sure I'm using a python3 interpreter but can't find the problem. For example:

```
import numpy as np
```

returns

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

and similarly for any other modules:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I have downloaded homebrew although I don't understand what it is (I'm a physicist not a programmer) and so far spent a few hours trying to figure it out. Any help would be great.

Comment: You have to install the modules via `pip3 install numpy` and such. If you can't import them via VSCode then that means it's using a different environment (such as a virtual environment) than the system environment (which is where packages get installed to). So, you'll have to make sure that you're installing the modules in the first place, and that you're installing them to the right environment. If you run into trouble with virtual environments, there's a lot of info on that that can be found with Google.

Comment: You need to install these packages before you can use them. In general, don't use "a python3 interpreter" - use the exact one that you intend to use! I suggest you do some research on setting up python virtual environments as this should be standard operating procedure. Please read your docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: Okay thank you for your help, I'll look into it. My coding education at university has been very much on a need to know basis and I haven't needed to know about virtual Environments, using the command line, etc until just now...

Answer (score 1):

Those two modules are third-part modules that need to be downloaded. The easiest/most common way to download is to use `pip`, which is a python module that should have come with your python install.

From the command line, run a `python3 -m pip install numpy matplotlib`. That will call python using the module pip, with the pip command 'install numpy maplotlib' (you can call them one-at-a-time if you like).

Once they are installed, you should be able to import them as you attempted above.

Comment: Yep that was the problem, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me before  when I tried to download the flask module,all I did was restart my vs-code and everything was working